# wxPython Panel not showing

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm playing around with wxPython.  My understanding is that you need the following items:
1. The main 'App'
2. A frame (or main window as I think of it)
3. A panel within the frame
4. Widgets within the panel to do things.

Think I'm OK with points 1 & 2 as I get a barebones window popup when I run my code.  However, I've tried to add a panel and some basic text to it - and nothing shows.

My code is:

```
import wx

class PDFApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):   #Method used to define Frame & show it

        self.frame = PDFFrame(parent=None, title="PDF Combiner", size=(300, 300))
        self.frame.Show()
        return True  

class PDFFrame(wx.Frame):
    def _init_(self, parent, title):
        super(PDFFrame, self).__init__(parent, title=title)

        Panel = PDFPanel(self)

class PDFPanel(wx.Panel):
    def _init_(self, parent):
        super(PDFPanel, self).__init__(parent)

        self.Label = wx.StaticText(self, label="hello")


App = PDFApp()
App.MainLoop()
```

Pointers to my error/ omissions- much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is unconventional in that `wx.App` is usually simply `app = wx.App()`
However, `_init_` should have been `__init__` and don't use variable names that can clash with reserved words or internals.
i.e. `Panel` or `Label` and probably `App` as well.
The following should function.

```
import wx

class PDFApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):   #Method used to define Frame & show it

        frame = PDFFrame(parent=None, title="PDF Combiner")
        frame.Show()
        return True  

class PDFFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        super(PDFFrame, self).__init__(parent, title=title)

        panel = PDFPanel(self)

class PDFPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(PDFPanel, self).__init__(parent)

        label = wx.StaticText(self, label="hello", pos=(50,100))


App = PDFApp()
App.MainLoop()
```

[image]

Edit:
I'm rather old fashioned (and self taught) so I'd code something as simple as this, like so:

```
import wx

class PdfFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1, title)
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        label = wx.StaticText(panel, -1, label="hello", pos=(50,100))
        self.Show()

app = wx.App()
frame = PdfFrame(None, title = "Simple Panel")
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: you don't know long I've spent trying to find that!! Thanks very much

Comment: Thanks very much for this - simple sounds good - especially for someone like me starting out!